# Stripe.Net invoice property is NULL when handling charge.refund webhook

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, webhooks, stripe.net

I am using Stripe.Net to handle the payments. When I start to test the "charge.refund" webhook, I am getting NULL invoice property in code behind but invoice value exists in Stripe webhook event and I confirmed the invoice is exist dashboard too.

Noticed the versions in Stripe.Net and configured webhook API is different.

Dashboard Webhook API version:  **2017-08-15**

Stripe.Net version: 16.12.0.0 (It support **2018-02-06**).

Here is the Stripe webhook event

[image]

Here is the breaking code(*charge.Invoice.SubscriptionId* breaking with Null reference)

[image]

Anybody faced this issue before?

Thanks

Comment: check the mapper, the target class and the JSON being parsed.

Comment: Stripe Charge Source code https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Entities/StripeCharge.cs#L182

Comment: Looking at the [source code for the mapper](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Infrastructure/Public/Mapper.cs#L28) and the fact the that the [invoice property is marked with JsonIgnore](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Entities/StripeCharge.cs#L182). What you describe is designed behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [source code for the `Stripe.Mapper<T>.MapFromJson`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Infrastructure/Public/Mapper.cs#L28)

```
// the ResponseJson on a list method is the entire list (as json) returned from stripe.
// the ObjectJson is so we can store only the json for a single object in the list on that entity for
// logging and/or debugging
public static T MapFromJson(string json, string parentToken = null, StripeResponse stripeResponse = null)
{
    var jsonToParse = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentToken) ? json : JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken(parentToken).ToString();

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonToParse);

    // if necessary, we might need to apply the stripe response to nested properties for StripeList<T>
    ApplyStripeResponse(json, stripeResponse, result);

    return result;
}

public static T MapFromJson(StripeResponse stripeResponse, string parentToken = null)
{
    return MapFromJson(stripeResponse.ResponseJson, parentToken, stripeResponse);
}

private static void ApplyStripeResponse(string json, StripeResponse stripeResponse, object obj)
{
    if (stripeResponse == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties())
    {
        if (property.Name == nameof(StripeResponse))
        {
            property.SetValue(obj, stripeResponse);
        }
    }

    stripeResponse.ObjectJson = json;
}
```

which is deserializing the JSON using JSON.Net,

the fact that the [`StripeCharge.Invoice` property is marked with `[JsonIgnore]` attribute](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Entities/StripeCharge.cs#L182).

```
#region Expandable Invoice

/// <summary>
/// ID of the invoice this charge is for if one exists.
/// </summary>
public string InvoiceId { get; set; }

[JsonIgnore]
public StripeInvoice Invoice { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("invoice")]
internal object InternalInvoice
{
    set
    {
        StringOrObject<StripeInvoice>.Map(value, s => this.InvoiceId = s, o => this.Invoice = o);
    }
}
#endregion
```

and finally how the `InternalInvoice` property is mapped via the `StringOrObject<T>`

```
StringOrObject<StripeInvoice>.Map(value, s => this.InvoiceId = s, o => this.Invoice = o);
```

You can see in the class definition

```
internal static class StringOrObject<T>
    where T : StripeEntityWithId
{
    public static void Map(object value, Action<string> updateId, Action<T> updateObject)
    {
        if (value is JObject)
        {
            T item = ((JToken)value).ToObject<T>();
            updateId(item.Id);
            updateObject(item);
        }
        else if (value is string)
        {
            updateId((string)value);
            updateObject(null);
        }
    }
}
```

That if the value passed is a `string`, that it will set the `Invoice` object property to null

```
else if (value is string)
{
    updateId((string)value);
    updateObject(null);
}
```

So the behavior you describe is as designed based on the shown data and code.

You would probably need to extract the `InvoiceId` and try to retrieve it (the invoice) in order to use its members.